# R - result in array

Tags: r

I have following data :

```
>   Product Location Start_Year WK_156 WK_155 WK_154 WK_153 WK_152 WK_151 WK_150 WK_149 WK_148 WK_147 WK_146
1  prod a ESK_PARK       2000      0     NA   4578   2926   2641   4900   2256   6652     NA   2112   1902
2  prod b ESK_PARK       2000      0     NA   4578   2926   2641   4900   2256   6652     NA   2112   1902
3  prod c ESK_PARK       2000      0     NA     NA   2926   2641   4900   2256   6652     NA   2112   1902
4  prod d ESK_PARK       2000      0     NA   4578   2926   2641   4900   2256   6652     NA   2112   1902
```

And am trying to loop and store some field in another array/list

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my.ds)) {
key[i,] <- my.ds[i,c(1,2)]
}
key
```

But here it returns me an error :

> Error: object 'key' not found

How can I create this list?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Try key <- NULL before loop,  or just  key <- my.ds[, c(1,2)].

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin assigning null doesn't help. Declare with my.ds[,c(1,2)] doesn't assign the result from the loop

How do I declare they object with n rows and m columns?

Comment: @mtoto this is something related to my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798184/azure-ml-batch-run-single-output

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was looking for [row merger](http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html) :

```
my.ds <- myDS2[, -c(4,5,6)]
key <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(my.ds)) {
  key <- rbind(key, my.ds[i,c(1,2)])
}
key
```